# iOS how to start a background task on local notification

Tags: ios, swift3, uilocalnotification, usernotifications, unusernotificationcenter

Im trying to achieve following. On delivering of a scheduled local notification a background task should be started to handle the app data so the user don't need to tap the notification or bring the app in the foreground. I'm supporting iOS 9+

Is this possible and if, how to do it?
AFAIK there is no event triggered on delivering a local notification in the AppDelegate or UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate if the app is in background or inactive.

Answer (score 0):

There is no event for local notification if the app is is terminated/killed or in background.

According to your problen, You can only trigger if your app is in foreground or if the user taps on the local notification

Comment: I thought so. Hm is there a possibility to schedule a background short task?

Comment: AFAIK, in background or killed state you can't do anything when your local notif arrive, You can do anything when you are in foreground in case of local notifications. Schedule a task whenever you are scheduling for local notifications

Comment: Thx. I will try it that way around - scheduling a bg task in foreground, and on finishing the bg task firing or scheduling a notification for it.